# re-render looses focus from text box (useState, multiple components)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

1. I have grid control and it has ability to Filter that grid based on the columns of the table.
2. Filter Components: Drop-down (Field selection), Drop-down (Operator equals, not equals, etc), text box (search/filter value)
3. I have used "useState" to store\set the value on the filter text box so that the value entered by User can persist). this is done using onChange event of the text box.

**Problem:** Whenever I type in the value in text box, OnChange is fired, useState sets the value on the text box to persist, **BUT** I loose the focus from the text box and goes to the end of pagination (below the data grid). *In short everything re-renders*.

**Other things:** This is a functional React TS component. Below is just a sample code to give you an idea.

I read about usememo and usecallback but I don't see good examples out there (will have a look in case someone suggests that it the answer to my problem).

**What I want to do :**

- Is there an alternate way to render only part of the component?
- stop re-rendering of other components but still set the value to persist for any of the other filter components.

**Sample Code**

```
export const datagrid = (props: datagridprops) => {
    const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState<string|undefined>();
    const onchangeval = (event) => { setSearchValue(event.target.value); }
    const renderData(){...}

    return(<>
            <input value={searchValue} onchange={onchangeval} />
            <table>{renderData()} />
            <pagination control />
    </>);
}
```

Let me know in case of any other questions.

**CLOSING THE QUESTION as useState WILL ALWAYS RENDER THE COMPONENT.**

Comment: autofocus has not worked. 
using key attribute has not worked.

Comment: If you need to render only a part of a component, that means you need to divide your components in sub components.

Comment: ok but I don't have that option. This filter  is part of that data grid. 
so is there a way to set the value using useState without re-rendering ?

since, there are many other variables which I have to maintain, like current page, sort column tracking, etc

Comment: Just based on that code it shouldn't lose focus just on that `onChange` so something else must be going on to cause that re-render. Is one of the props changing?

Comment: no Andy, nothing else is changing. I could see when I comment the code of OnChange, the re-render of grid (table) stops.  But if I do that, I cannot apply the filter bcz the Filter value provided by User will always be empty.

Comment: will setting any other useState variable (not a property) also re-render the component ?
if yes, how am I supposed to keep track of such metadata without re-rendering. do I have to use another hook ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CLOSING THE QUESTION as useState WILL ALWAYS RENDER THE COMPONENT.**

I may have to useMemo in case I want to store in-between states of a variable\logic without useState. somehow defeating the purpose of re-rendering and usestate